# Disable the option for personal regional settings

Tags: 2010, powershell, regional-settings

Is there a way (through PowerShell or an other method) to disable the option for users to set [personal regional settings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2009/07/01/time-zones-in-sharepoint-and-date-time-stamp-format.aspx)? I have a system where I want to force users to be on UTC since changing regional settings only affects some datetime fields (InfoPath forms, specifically, don't adjust their entries for regional time settings).

My nuclear option is to remove "Edit Personal User Information" permissions from all permission groups, but I was hoping that a more targeted solution was available.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by editing regionalsetng.aspx in the LAYOUTS folder. Adding `disabled="disabled"` to `asp:CheckBox id="ChkFollowWebRegionalSettings"` has the desired effect.